# Integration test DBUnit NoSuchTableException Java

Tags: java, xml

When i start the test i have this **NoSuchTableException**. Do i need to set the same name of in-memory data base like that in production ?

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @ContextConfiguration
    @TestExecutionListeners({ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class,
            TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class, DbUnitTestExecutionListener.class })
    @DatabaseSetup(type = DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT, value = "login.xml")
    public class LoginControllerTest {

        private MockMvc mockMvc;

        @Before
        public void setUp() {
            mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.xmlConfigSetup("loginControllerTest-context.xml").build();
        }

        @Test
        @ExpectedDatabase("login.xml")
        public void testShowForm() throws Exception {
            mockMvc.perform(get("/login")).andExpect(status().isOk()).andExpect(view().name("/login"))
                    .andExpect(forwardedUrl("/WebContent/j/login.jsp"))
                    .andExpect(model().attribute("form", hasProperty("id", nullValue())))
                    .andExpect(model().attribute("form", hasProperty("email", isEmptyOrNullString())))
                    .andExpect(model().attribute("form", hasProperty("username", isEmptyOrNullString())))
                    .andExpect(model().attribute("form", hasProperty("hostname", isEmptyOrNullString())))
                    .andExpect(model().attribute("form", hasProperty("pass", isEmptyOrNullString())));
        }
    }
```

This here is **loginControllerTest-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.profiles.controller.test" />

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:login" />
        <property name="username" value="sa" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**This here is login.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataset>
    <person id="1" email="qwerty@asdf.com" username="qwerty"
        hostname="asdf.com" pass="password1234" />

    <person id="2" email="zxcvb@asdf.com" username="zxcvb"
        hostname="asdf.com" pass="password1234" />
</dataset>
```

At last but not least **Stack Trace**

```
org.dbunit.dataset.NoSuchTableException: person
    at org.dbunit.database.DatabaseDataSet.getTableMetaData(DatabaseDataSet.java:288)
    at org.dbunit.operation.DeleteAllOperation.execute(DeleteAllOperation.java:109)
    at org.dbunit.operation.CompositeOperation.execute(CompositeOperation.java:79)
    at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitRunner.setupOrTeardown(DbUnitRunner.java:159)
    at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitRunner.beforeTestMethod(DbUnitRunner.java:70)
    at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitTestExecutionListener.beforeTestMethod(DbUnitTestExecutionListener.java:136)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.beforeTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:277)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.runBefores(SpringMethodRoadie.java:315)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(SpringMethodRoadie.java:253)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.runWithRepetitions(SpringMethodRoadie.java:234)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.runTest(SpringMethodRoadie.java:204)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.run(SpringMethodRoadie.java:146)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.invokeTestMethod(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:151)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.runMethods(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:51)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner$1.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:27)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:37)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)

junit.framework.ComparisonFailure: table count expected:<[1]> but was:<[0]>
    at org.dbunit.assertion.JUnitFailureFactory.createFailure(JUnitFailureFactory.java:39)
    at org.dbunit.assertion.DefaultFailureHandler.createFailure(DefaultFailureHandler.java:105)
    at org.dbunit.assertion.DbUnitAssert.assertEquals(DbUnitAssert.java:237)
    at org.dbunit.assertion.DbUnitAssert.assertEquals(DbUnitAssert.java:205)
    at org.dbunit.Assertion.assertEquals(Assertion.java:104)
    at com.github.springtestdbunit.assertion.DefaultDatabaseAssertion.assertEquals(DefaultDatabaseAssertion.java:33)
    at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitRunner.verifyExpected(DbUnitRunner.java:128)
    at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitRunner.afterTestMethod(DbUnitRunner.java:80)
    at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitTestExecutionListener.afterTestMethod(DbUnitTestExecutionListener.java:141)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.afterTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:340)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.runAfters(SpringMethodRoadie.java:351)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(SpringMethodRoadie.java:262)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.runWithRepetitions(SpringMethodRoadie.java:234)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.runTest(SpringMethodRoadie.java:204)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.run(SpringMethodRoadie.java:146)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.invokeTestMethod(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:151)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.runMethods(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:51)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner$1.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:27)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:37)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Comment: How did you create the table?

Comment: @Thilo I thought that login.xml care about that ?

Answer (score 0):

For integration Testing dataset should contain valid table names, so YES you need to have same table names for your test to be executed successfully.